# Overiding the auth module's AuthticationForm to allow logging in via email

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-forms, django-authentication

I'd like to allow my users to be able to log in via email. I've seen examples of accomplishing this by writing a custom authentication back-end. I, however, would like to do this by inheriting the `django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm` and adding a new field called `email` which on the `clean_email` method fetches the username from the `User` model and then passes it to the parent form.

I've tried doing this but I've failed miserably as I can't seem to modify the request or populate the field value. This is what I've gotten so far.

```
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(
        required=True, label=_("Email")
    )

    def __init__(self, request=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(
            request, *args, **kwargs
        )
        self.fields['username'].widget = forms.widgets.HiddenInput()

    def clean_email(self):
        user = User.objects.filter(email=self.cleaned_data['email'])
        if user:
            #self.fields['username'].value = user.username
            #return user.email
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("Incorrect email or password."))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `clean` if you want to modify another field:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    user = User.objects.filter(email=cleaned_data['email'])
    if user:
        cleaned_data['username'] = user.username
    else:
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("Incorrect email or password."))
    return cleaned_data
```

And don't forget that email isn't unique in Django auth.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this (untested):

```
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].label = u'E-mail'

    def clean_username(self):
        # get user from e-mail address, minding possible exceptions
        return user.username
```